# How to specify range in an implicit relationship with variable?

Tags: code-request

Here is the plot I want to do:

```
ContourPlot[3 Abs[x] y (y^2/x^2 - 1/3) - 2/(Abs[x] y) == 3 Sqrt[1 - y^2/x^2], {x, -20, 20}, {y/x, 1/Sqrt[3], 1}]
```

However when I evaluate this in mathematica notebook an error occurs, pointing to mathematica being unable to understand the part '{y/x,1/Sqrt[3],1}'. Is there a way to get around this without altering the boundary condition?

Comment: How about `{y, x/Sqrt[3], x}`? Or `...{y, -20, 20}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 1/Sqrt[3] < y/x < 1]...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides of using `ContourPlot`,we can also use `ImplicitRegion` or `RegionPlot` to do such example.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{3 Abs[x] y (y^2/x^2 - 1/3) - 2/(Abs[x] y) == 
     3 Sqrt[1 - y^2/x^2], -20 <= x <= 20, 1/Sqrt[3] <= y/x <= 1}, {x, 
    y}];
RegionPlot[reg, PlotRange -> {-20, 20}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

Or use `Reduce` or `Solve` at first to looking for the range of such curves.

```
sol = Reduce[{3 Abs[x] y (y^2/x^2 - 1/3) - 2/(Abs[x] y) == 
    3 Sqrt[1 - y^2/x^2], -20 <= x <= 20,1/Sqrt[3] <= y/x <= 1}]
```

> `(y == -1 && x == -1) || (-1 < y <= Root[-2 + 9 #^4& , 1, 0] &&  x == Root[4 - 3 y^4 + 9 y^8 + (-5 y^2 - 6 y^6) #1^2 + y^4 #1^4 &,  2]) || (y == 1 &&  x == 1) || (1 < y <= Root[ 4 - 2000 #^2 + 159997 #^4 - 2400 #^6 + 9 #^8& , 8, 0] &&  x == Root[4 - 3 y^4 + 9 y^8 + (-5 y^2 - 6 y^6) #1^2 + y^4 #1^4 &,  3])`

Then we can use `RegionPlot`(since `DiscretizeRegion` cann't work) or `ParametricPlot` to draw such curves.

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[sol, {x, y}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Or

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{Root[
    4 - 3 y^4 + 9 y^8 + (-5 y^2 - 6 y^6) #1^2 + y^4 #1^4 &, 2], 
   y}, {y, -1, Root[-2 + 9 #^4& , 1, 0]}],
 ParametricPlot[{Root[
    4 - 3 y^4 + 9 y^8 + (-5 y^2 - 6 y^6) #1^2 + y^4 #1^4 &, 3], 
   y}, {y, 1, Root[
   4 - 2000 #^2 + 159997 #^4 - 2400 #^6 + 9 #^8& , 8, 0]}], 
 Graphics[{Red, Point[{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]}], PlotRange -> All, 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

As recommended by Michael E2, use [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html)

```
Legended[
 Show[
  ContourPlot[
   3 Abs[x] y (y^2/x^2 - 1/3) - 2/(Abs[x] y) == 3 Sqrt[1 - y^2/x^2], {x, -20, 
    20}, {y, -20, 20}, ContourStyle -> LightGray,
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   MaxRecursion -> 4],
  ContourPlot[
   3 Abs[x] y (y^2/x^2 - 1/3) - 2/(Abs[x] y) == 3 Sqrt[1 - y^2/x^2], {x, -20, 
    20}, {y, -20, 20},
   ContourStyle -> Red,
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 1/Sqrt[3] <= y/x <= 1], PlotPoints -> 50,
   MaxRecursion -> 3]],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[{LightGray, Red}, {"Unconstrained", "Constrained"}],
  {0.5, 0.85}]]
```

[image]